# HTML - How to display "LOGIN" if member name CLASS is empty

Tags: html, hide

Basically it would would be super great if someone can provide a pointer on how to achieve this.

I use a 3rd SAS and when logged in to it, it returns the username to class="SFnam" which can be displayed on any page that has the associated JS embedded in the bottom of the page.

At the moment I use the following html to display the Users Name in the top right of the screen when logged in: i.e. "Logged in as: BORIS SMITH", however when a users NOT not logged in it displays "Logged in as:".  Not ideal.

How can I display "LOGIN" if the class="SFnam" is empty?

Here's what I'm using (After Rafaels input):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    var spanElm = document.getElementById('myspan');

    if(spanElm.classList.contains('SFnam'))
    {
          console.log('here');
    }
    else
    {
        console.log('here instead');
        document.getElementsByTagName('user')[0].innerHTML = "LOGIN";
    }
});
 </script>
 <style>
 #loginwrapper {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px Opx;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
 }
 .logincontainer {  text-align: right;}
 user {
    display: inline-flex;
    background-color: #1f7665; color: #fff;
    padding:2px 3px 1px 3px;
    font-size:8px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-family: Raleway, Arial, Helvetica, 'Liberation Sans', FreeSans, sans-serif;
 }
 </style>
 <div id="loginwrapper" title ="Click to Log in/out" onclick="window.open('/member-login.html','_self')">
    <div class="logincontainer">
            <user>Logged in as:&nbsp; <b><span style="text-transform:uppercase;" class="SFnam" id='myspan'></span></b>
    </div>
 </div>
```

When logged in the span result is: 
       < span class="SFnam">Boris Smith< /span >

When logged out the span result is:
     < span class="SFnam">< /span>

I am reasonably new to this however have some skills with basic coding etc so apologies if the above has not been constructed poorly :(.

Any guidance / assistance will be gratefully appreciated.

Cheers
Boris

EDITED:
Also of note is the Listener script at the bottom of each page (not sure if that helps?:

```
 <script>(function(){var i,j,a,x;try{x=localStorage.getItem("SF_nam");}catch(e){x="";}
 try{for(a=document.querySelectorAll(".SFnam"),i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a[i].innerHTML=x?x:"";}catch(e){}
 try{for(a=document.querySelectorAll(".SF_li"),i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a[i].style.display=x?"":"none";}catch(e){}
 try{for(a=document.querySelectorAll(".SF_lo"),i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a[i].style.display=x?"none":"";}catch(e){}})();
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will change the element's text accordingly to that span class containing text or not.

```
function updateSpan()
{
     var spanElm = document.getElementById('myspan');
        if(spanElm.innerHTML)
        {
              document.getElementsByTagName('user')[0].innerHTML = "Logged in as " + spanElm.innerHTML;
        }
        else
        {

            document.getElementsByTagName('user')[0].innerHTML = "LOGIN";
        }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        updateSpan();

    });
```

add an id to your span so we can locate it

```
<span style="text-transform:uppercase;"class="SFnam" id='myspan'></span>
```

update your bottom script with this

```
<script>(function(){var i,j,a,x;try{x=localStorage.getItem("SF_nam");}catch(e){x="";}
 try{for(a=document.querySelectorAll(".SFnam"),i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a[i].innerHTML=x?x:"";}catch(e){}
 try{for(a=document.querySelectorAll(".SF_li"),i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a[i].style.display=x?"":"none";}catch(e){}
 try{for(a=document.querySelectorAll(".SF_lo"),i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)a[i].style.display=x?"none":"";}catch(e){}
updateSpan()})();
 </script>
```

This will make sure the function is also updated if changes happen during execution time.
Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r3csgk93/3/)

Comment: Thanks Rafael for the super fast response!  Amazing!  I implemented the above exactly as you outlined however when "logged out" the text "Logged in as:" remains.  It does changed between "Logged in as:" and "Logged in as: Boris Smith" however LOGIN does not appear instead of "Logged in as:" ? Not sure if I did something wrong?  Perhaps SFnam isn't really empty?  Looking at the results in the console when logged in/out the span appears empty when logged out so am not sure.  I can repost my code again?

Comment: Please locate your span using the browser inspector, and see what happens when you're logged in and not logged in. If you can, post exactly how it looks in both situations, edit the question and include those details.

Comment: I've updated the code with your suggestion and posted span results as seen in FF and added the listener script provided by the 3rd party as maybe that can be changed?

Comment: Thanks Rafael!  Implemented and it works... kind of.  The status of the displayed text does not change on the fly when logging in / out (like it did before) however the correct result appears on a page refresh.  This is the same for logging in and out.  Previously as soon as I logged in/out the result would be immediate without any page refresh.  Also with your fix the "text-transform:uppercase" does not work and the Users name remains in proper case?